# Achieve where condition and case statement if null

Tags: sql-server

Below is my where condition in query

```
WHERE ResetID= CASE WHEN  NOT EXISTS (select  1 FROM ops.table where LabelItemId=@Item) THEN NULL  
                              WHEN @LastIssued < @LastDispatched THEN  1                                                           
                              WHEN  @LastIssued >= @LastDispatched  THEN  2
                              END
```

If case statement  returns  null the where condition will not work.. Any alternate solution for this condition without case

Comment: In main table  ResetID has null values..so i want to retrieve retrieve  resetid with null values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have `NULL = NULL`, you need to handle it with `IS NULL`. At a guess, what you want is this:

```
WHERE (ResetID = CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (select  1 FROM ops.table where LabelItemId=@Item) THEN NULL  
                      WHEN @LastIssued < @LastDispatched THEN  1                                                           
                      WHEN @LastIssued >= @LastDispatched  THEN  2
                 END
   OR (ResetID IS NULL AND NOT EXISTS (select  1 FROM ops.table where LabelItemId=@Item)))
```

*Edit note that this does require 2 scans of the table `ops.table`; there may be a better way to do this, but difficult to suggest when we only have a snippet.*